# Changing on which slide the `toc` appears in RevealJs slides using Quarto

Tags: reveal.js, quarto

I am using Quarto to produce some `revealjs` slides and would like the table of contents to appear on an arbitrary slide rather than immediately after the title slide. Is there a way of achieving this?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

We can place the table of contents at an arbitrary slide at an arbitrary place with the help of [RevealJs Partials](https://quarto.org/docs/journals/templates.html#revealjs-partials) [`toc-slide.html`](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/blob/main/src/resources/formats/revealjs/pandoc/toc-slide.html). I have modified it a bit and also used javascript (in `toc-add.html`) to change the TOC position. **Note that, using RevealJs partials requires Quarto version 1.2 at least.**

Suppose we want to add the TOC in the `overview` slide, so we create an HTML div as a placeholder for the TOC as follows,

````
```{=html}
<div id='toc'></div>
```
````

and then using javascript, we can fetch the TOC generated by quarto and replace the `<div id='toc'></div>` with the TOC.

**quarto-revealjs.qmd**

````
---
title: "Controlling TOC"
format: 
  revealjs:
    toc: true
    template-partials: 
      - toc-slide.html
    include-after-body: toc-add.html
---

## Quarto  

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a
finished presentation.

## Overview

This is the overview slide.

```{=html}
<div id='toc'></div>
```

This slide contain the contents that we going to discuss and hopyfully things
wiil make sense :). 

## Code

You can embed code like this:

```{r}
#| echo: true
1 + 1
```
````

**toc-slide.html**

```
<section id="$idprefix$TOC">
<nav id="toc-nav" role="doc-toc" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">  
$if(toc-title)$
<h3 id="$idprefix$toc-title">$toc-title$</h3>
$endif$
$table-of-contents$
</nav>
</section>
```

**toc-add.html**

```
<script>
  let placeholder = document.querySelector("div#toc");
  let toc = document.querySelector("#toc-nav");
  let toc_slide = document.querySelector("section#TOC");
  
  let toc_clone = toc.cloneNode(true);
  placeholder.replaceWith(toc_clone);
  
  toc_slide.remove();
</script>
```

**Rendered Output** (in slide overview mode)

---

[image: TOC at arbitrary slide]

---

Comment: Thanks for this! The first option you provide works, but seems to mess up the slide numbering and stops some background videos I have in the presentation from working. The second version results in an error: 

`ERROR: The format 'revealjs' only supports the following partials:
metadata.html
title-block.html
toc.html

Please provide one or more of these partials.`

Renaming toc-slide.html as toc.html allows the presentation to compile but the toc doesn't appear in the correct slide (it appears in the default position just after the title slide still).

Comment: Yikes! I had the feeling option 01 is way too messy. But the error you are facing in using revealjs partial is because probably you have quarto version lower than 1.2. Can you check that?

Comment: Hi - no, I am using quarto 1.2 so I don't think it is that!

Comment: But this [link](https://quarto.org/docs/journals/templates.html#revealjs-partials) to quarto Docs mentions about `toc-slide.html`. Ok I will look into this, ASAP!

Comment: The above answer works for me as shown in the above images and I am using qurato version `‘1.2.235’`. So I am not sure what's causing problems in your case :( . But maybe you can rename the file `toc-slide.html` to `toc.html` and use that. How about that?